# Table already exists MySQL.Data, Error 1050

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis

I am trying to create a connection that links MySQL database to SQL Server using visual studio code. So far I have created an SSIS package that I have named child.extract and I have created an ado.net connection and parameterized it as shown below:

[image: Connection Manager parameterised]

In the dataflow, I created a source table and destination tables. Now I'm trying to a SQL command to the source table and I'm getting this error when previewing:

[image: Preview]

[image: Preview Error]

I am not seeing the table so what should I do?. I have tried to drop the table in MySQL and it's not working.

Comment: What about the error don't you understand here? The error is telling you the problem; the table already exists. Though, I must admit, having a `CREATE` statement in a Dataflow source node doesn't make a lot of sense. Why are you creating a table when you are designing the node where you define where the data *comes from*?

Comment: but I must select the source table right? thta is why i am using mysql command. how then do i connect the two tables if i cant have the source table?

Comment: You can `SELECT` the data, sure, you when you want to `SELECT` data from a table you don't `CREATE` it; it's already created.  What you are doing doesn't make any sense.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)